# How to get the list of image files only in a folder

Tags: qt

I want to get the names of image files (*.png, *.jpg, *.bmp) from a folder.

What I could do so far is this :

```
 fileInfoList = dir.entryInfoList(QDir::Files|QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
```

But how to get only the *.png, *.bmp and *.jpg files ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this should work;

```
 QStringList filters;
 filters << "*.png" << "*.jpg" << "*.bmp";
 fileInfoList = dir.entryInfoList(filters, QDir::Files|QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
```

See [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html#entryInfoList) for more info.

You can also use the [QDir::setNameFilters](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html#setNameFilters) function to set the filters.